# How to combine and update a data set in SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

Hi guy I'm working is SAS platform and I've a table as

```
dimension
rk | 1_nm | 2_rk | 2_nm | 2_parent_rk | 3_rk | 3_nm | 3_parent_rk

1    one     -     -        -            -      -        -
2    two     -     -        -            -      -        -
3     -       3    three    1            -      -        -
4     -       4    four     1            -      -        -
5     -       5    five     2            -      -        -
6     -       6    six      2            -      -        -
7     -       -     -       -            7      seven    3
8     -       -     -       -            8      eight    3
9     -       -     -       -            9      nine     5
```

I want to simply this data set and I want it to convert as.

```
rk  | 1_nm |   2_nm        |   3_nm
1     one     -                -
2     two     -                -
3     one     one three        -
4     one     one four         -
5     two     two five         -
6     two     two six          -
7     one     one three     one three seven
8     one     one three     one three eight
9     two     two five      two five nine
```

this is what I've tried

```
proc sql noprint;
create table dim as
select * 
from dimension;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
update dimension
set 1_nm = (select tbl.1_nm from dim as tbl where dimension.2_parent_rk eq tbl.rk); 
quit;
```

I'm stuck and can't find anything that what approach I should use. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you simply want a `join`.  Given your structure, an `update` doesn't seem appropriate -- because your result has different columns from the input.  You can use the following to create a new table.

```
proc sql;
    select rk, d.1_nm,
           (case when d2.2_nm is not null then d.1_nm || ' ' || d2.2_nm end) as 2_nm,
           (ase when d3.3_nm is not null then d.1_nm || ' ' || d2.2_nm || ' ' || d3.3_nm end) as 3_nm
    from dimension d left join
         dimension d2
         on d2.2_parent_rk = d.rk left join
         dimension d3
         on d3.3_parent_rk = d2.rk;
```

Comment: Thanks for identifying an approach. It's working but its merging every record. I'm having record as 1 ,one, one four, one four, ,,,,,  1 ,one, one three, one three eight and records of rk 2-9 are empty.

Comment: Yeah, that join is another way around (child-to-parent). The way it would be done in SQL is using recursive CTEs, which [SAS doesn't appear have](https://yazispring.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/recursive-query-in-sas-and-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in update if you actually want all those columns and are just being sparse in your question.  You can use `UNDO_POLICY=NONE` to do this with just one table, or you can do it in two tables as you do above.

It's just going to take a bunch of queries, as SAS is basically just ANSI SQL in this regard.  First I update both nm_2 and rk_2_parent in the rk_3_parent group; then I update rk_1 for all of those (so the changes for 3 flow down to 2).  Then I do a final update that doesn't require a join to get the names right (unfortunately you can't do that inline as SAS for some reason doesn't wait to calculate the second field in the update until after the first has found a match- not sure why, but SQL is odd about things like that).

```
data dimension;
length nm_1 nm_2 nm_3$50;
input rk_1 nm_1 $ rk_2  nm_2 $ rk_2_parent  rk_3   nm_3 $ rk_3_parent;
datalines;
1    one     .     .        .            .      .        .
2    two     .     .        .            .      .        .
3     .       3    three    1            .      .        .
4     .       4    four     1            .      .        .
5     .       5    five     2            .      .        .
6     .       6    six      2            .      .        .
7     .       .     .       .            7      seven    3
8     .       .     .       .            8      eight    3
9     .       .     .       .            9      nine     5
;;;;
run;

proc sql undo_policy=none;
  update dimension master
  set nm_2 = (
        select nm_2
        from dimension parent
        where parent.rk_2 = master.rk_3_parent
        )
        where master.rk_3 is not null
    ;
update dimension master
  set rk_2_parent = (
        select rk_2_parent
        from dimension parent
        where parent.rk_2 = master.rk_3_parent
        )
        where master.rk_3_parent is not null
    ;

  update dimension master
    set nm_1 = (
        select nm_1
        from dimension parent
        where parent.rk_1 = master.rk_2_parent
        )
        where master.rk_2_parent is not null
    ;
  update dimension master
    set nm_2 = catx(' ',nm_1,nm_2),
        nm_3 = catx(' ',nm_1,nm_2,nm_3);

quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what does UNDO_POLICY=NONE do?